# Get date value from crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I've get value "SDFE12:56" from database, but in my report, i only want to show 12:56 under the colume Time. Is there a way to do that? I've already tried by Ctime()function. but it seems not working

thanks

Answer (score 1):

try `val` function

```
val(SDFE12:56)
```

if you want check [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic666.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the same lay as your other question

Mid ("SDFE12:56",4 ,5 )

or because it is at then end you can do

Mid ("SDFE12:56",4)